# Select me retorna nulo, na segunda iteração do laço FOR, em diante

Tags: java, android

Tenho uma base de dados, `ROOM`, que faço um select logo após o retorno de uma `asyncTask`. Pego o retorno e faço um `select`, esperando o retorno deste `select`.

Funciona normalmente, na primeira iteração do `for`, mas da segunda em diante, o retorno é sempre nulo. Os dados estão na base dados e deveria sim me retornar.

Se eu faço pelo <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd>, os dados me retornam, na query. Mas pelo `for`, fica nulo.

Por que isso acontece?

AppDataBase:

```
private AppDataBase appDataBase;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_atendimento_tab);

    appDataBase = AppDataBase.getInstance(this);
}

@Database(entities = {CidVo.class}, version = 8, exportSchema = false)
public abstract class AppDataBase extends RoomDatabase {

 public abstract CidDao getCidDao();

    private static AppDataBase appDataBase;

    public static AppDataBase getInstance(Context context) {
        if (null == appDataBase) {
            appDataBase = buildDataBaseInstance(context);
        }
        return appDataBase;
    }

    private static AppDataBase buildDataBaseInstance(Context context) {
        return Room.databaseBuilder(context,
                AppDataBase.class,
                "AutoCompleteVo")
                .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
                .allowMainThreadQueries().build();
    }

    //CID predicted
    public CidVo getCid(Context context, String idCidVo) {
        if (appDataBase == null) {
            appDataBase = AppDataBase.getInstance(context);
        }
        return appDataBase.getCidDao().getCidVo("%" + idCidVo + "%");
    }
}
```

DAO:

```
@Dao
public interface CidDao {
    //CID
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    void insertAllCID(List<CidVo> cidVos);

    @Query("Select * from CidVo WHERE idCid = :idCid")
    CidVo getCidVo(String idCid);

}
```

FOR:

```
@Override
    public void retornoAsyncTaskResultPredict(AsyncTaskResult<Retorno> asyncTaskResult) {
        if (asyncTaskResult.getExceptionResult() == null) {

            RetornoPredicaoCid predicaoCidVo = (RetornoPredicaoCid) asyncTaskResult.getResult();

            if (predicaoCidVo.getRetorno() != null) {

                List<PredicaoCidVo> predCid = predicaoCidVo.getRetorno();
                List<CidVo> predictedText = new ArrayList<>();
                List<CidVo> predictedText1 = new ArrayList<>();

                for (int i = 0;i<predCid.size();i++) {
                    //appDataBase = AppDataBase.getInstance(this);
                    CidVo cidVo = appDataBase.getCidDao().getCidVo(predCid.get(i).getTextPredicted());
                    CidVo cidVo1 = appDataBase.getCid(this, predCid.get(i).getTextPredicted());
                    predictedText1.add(cidVo1);
                    predictedText.add(cidVo);
                }


            }
    }
```

Comment: se o problema não está na consulta (ou seja, tem dados) deve estar no controle do _async_ (não respondo porque não manjo, foi mal =p)

Comment: O async já foi feito, este é o retorno, somente.

Comment: Na segunda iteração, perde a instancia, me parece do getCidVo, mas não entendo o motivo.

Answer (score 0):

Na segunda iteração em diante, os itens passaram a vir com um espaço no início ou final, causando o problema.
Resolvido com um simples `.trim()`;

```
predCid.get(i).getTextPredicted().trim()
```